# Unable to connect to chef-server

Tags: chef, knife

Cannot connect to the chef-server from a workstation. Tried command "knife node list"

```
Network Error: Error connecting to https://<chef-server-address>/nodes - Failed to open TCP connection to <chef-server-address> 
(getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Check your knife configuration and network settings
```

Here is my knife file

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "node-name"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/<chef-server-address>.pem"
validation_client_name   "chef-validator"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/chef-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://<chef-server-address>"
cache_type               'BasicFile'
cache_options( :path => "#{ENV['HOME']}/.chef/checksums" )
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```

Comment: on you chef server what does `hostname -f` gives you?

Answer (score -2):

```
chef_server_url          "https://<chef-server-address>"
```

Change this parameter, and paste actual address of your chef server